# RxDataSources testing

Tags: testing, tdd, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I have created tableView with sections by RxDataSources.

ViewController

```
viewModel.sectionsObservable
        .bindTo(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: viewModel.dataSource))
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

sectionsObservable emits the event when a new element is added to the array.

I would like to test if a proper element is on proper indexPath.

```
func testGettingElementForIndexPath() {
    let element = Element()
    viewModel.addElement(element)
    let fetchedElement = viewModel.getElement(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
    XCTAssertEqual(element, fetchedElement)
}
```

ViewModel

```
func getElement(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Element {
    return self.dataSource.sectionModels[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
}
```

it works in the app, but tests fail. fatal error: Index out of range

It's all because of that asynchronous. How to test this case?

---

EDIT 1:
ViewModel

```
let elementsVariable = Variable<[TaskData]>([])
func addElement(_ element: Element) {
    elementsVariable.value.append(element)
}

var sectionsObservable: Observable<[Day]> {
    return elementsVariable.asObservable().map { (elements) -> [MySection] in
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say that the production code works fine it has to be some silly mistake.

In production code you have:

`.bindTo(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: viewModel.dataSource))`

which internally sets items inside the dataSource

Check if you also have it inside the test code

Comment: I think dataSource.sectionModels doesn't have enough time to become updated and  XCTAssert runs faster async

Comment: Do you change a `scheduler` somewhere? If not I think it is not a case here.

But maybe...

Comment: If it so I would say is a problem with architecture design. Methods like `addElement` `getElement` are reactive code smell (because they are not reactive but imperative) :(

However, you haven't answered my question yet :D. Do you subscribe for `viewModel.dataSource` somewhere inside the test code?

Comment: I'll create some demo locally on the weekend and try to play with it. Is hard to help you without the code in front of me :P